# Obstacle avoidance opencv robot

Tags: c++, opencv

Hi I am using opencv and am trying to create an obstacle avoiding project. I write my code in c++ and am planning to use RANSAC and optical flow info in order to detect the obstacles . Is this method right ? What else could i use ?

I am not quite interested in the precision but I want to avoid some walls or other static objects in a room.

Comment: you might wanna look to fuzzy logic for your avoidance algorithm

Comment: I would like to try it with simple opencv functions . I have seen similar projects that work .